# Is this even possible to compute?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

One of my homework questions was the following (please see image). However, I ask myself if it is even possible to compute it without any extra knowledge about the sequence itself.

There were some subquestions about this exercise, which for example assumed beta to be 1; however, I do not think that it is allowed to assume such things for this certain question.

But if there is no way to solve this question without any other assumptions than the one in the image, then I guess I will be having to use the assumptions of the other subquestions regarding this sequence.

Thank you very much in adv[image]ance.

Comment: EDIT: I personally just noticed that it is possible to rewrite the lim an to lim an+1 and then use the limit laws for sequences to get a certain 'simplified' limit depending on the lim of an+1.

Then, as lim an = L, I would be able to state that lim an+1 = L

Therefore, I would be able to set L equal to the limit of an and, but then I get:

L^2 = -1/2 

Which would require me to use the imaginary number 'i'.. Does that make any sense?

Comment: As a hint, note that, if the sequence does in fact approach a limit $L$, then $L=4-\frac 2L$, which seriously narrows down the possible values for $L$.  Of course, you still need to argue that the limit even exists.

Comment: No, $L$ is not imaginary.  Starting with $a_0=1$ is sensible.  Just write out the first few dozen terms (use a machine).  You'll see what happens numerically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies, greatly appreciate it.
I tried solving L = 4 - (2/L) for L, which makes way more sense than the method I described (thanks) and I got two L values. Namely, -sqrt(2)+2 and sqrt(2)+2.

I tried to write out the first few terms and they approach 4 if a0 = 1.

Comment: $4$?  Certainly not.  As you remark, if the sequence converges (which, by the way, it does) then it can only converge to one of $2\pm \sqrt 2$.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I do not understand how I came to the number 4.. I really messed up somehow there. I think I got this now. 

Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a clue in the question, which is entitled "Monotone convergent sequences". Here's the most mechanical way of doing it:

- Find conditions under which the sequence is monotone. (You will have various cases depending on $\beta$.)
- Prove that the sequence [almost always] eventually reaches a point where it becomes monotone for the rest of time.
- Prove that the sequence is [almost always] bounded below.
- Prove that the sequence is [almost always] bounded above.
- Deduce that the sequence [almost always] converges.
- Find the two possible limits, and show that the sequence in fact [almost always] only converges to one of them.

Note that there are cases where the sequence fails to be even well-defined, so you need to rule those out first.

Comment: Thank you very much, I totally forgot to rule out the undefined cases as well. Greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

The map $T:\>x\mapsto 4-{2\over x}$ can be viewed as restriction of a Moebius transformation $T:\>\bar{\mathbb C}\to\bar{\mathbb C}$ to $\bar{\mathbb R}$. The fixed points of $T$ are obtained by solving the equation $x=4-{2\over x}$, and are $2\pm\sqrt{2}$. This suggests to introduce in $\bar {\mathbb C}$ the new complex projective coordinate
$$u={x-2-\sqrt{2}\over x-2+\sqrt{2}}=:S(x)\ .$$
With respect to $u$ the given $T$ computes to
$$u\mapsto \hat T(u)=S\circ T\circ S^{-1}(u)=(3-2\sqrt{2})u\ .$$
Since $3-2\sqrt{2}=0.1716$ it follows that in the $u$-system the point $u_1=0$ is an attracting fixed point of $\hat T$, and $u_2=\infty$ is a repelling fixed point of $\hat T$. In terms of the variable $x$ this means that $x_0=2+\sqrt{2}$ is attracting, and $x_1=2-\sqrt{2}$ is repelling. Concerning the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ in the question we therefore can say that it converges to $2+\sqrt{2}$, whatever the initial point $a_0$, as long as $a_0\ne2-\sqrt{2}$.